# What is and isn't available to class methods in python?

Tags: python

My limited understand is that the second argument to types.FunctionTypes (`dict`) determines what is available to the function code. I'm curious how it gets gets decided when instantiating functions internally. To illustrate what I mean, if I try to copy a function dynamically:

```
a = 'test'
def foo():
    print(a)

bar = types.FunctionType(
    foo.__code__, 
    globals(), 
    'bar', 
    foo.__defaults__, 
    foo.__closure__
)
```

This seems to work fine with globals(), but am I missing anything? More confusing is a class method. If I do something like this:

```
a = 'test'

class Foo(object):
    b = 'Foo prints this'

    def myfunc():
        print(a, self.b)

Bar = type('Bar', tuple(), dict())
Bar.b = 'Bar prints this'

ns = globals()
#should I do ns.update(something) here?

f = Foo.myfunc
Bar.myfunc = types.FunctionType(f.__code__, ns, 'myfunc', ...)
```

That example works, but not this more complicated one:

```
import imp
import builtins

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() # super(Foo, self) also fails

mod = imp.new_module('test')
mod.__builtins__ = builtins
mod.Foo = type('Foo', tuple(), dict())

f = Foo.__init__
ns = {}
ns.update(mod.__dict__) #missing something here

mod.Foo.__init__ = types.FunctionTypes(f.__code__, ns, '__init__', ...)
```

Could someone illuminate what should be in `ns`? What is available to a class method, and what isn't?

I'm not specifically trying to get the above code to work, I'm more looking for an explanation of why it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that "copying" the `__closure__` attribute doesn't create a copy;  that's the execution context in which the function body, (the `def __init__`) was itself executed; in support of the lexical scoping rules in the python language.  Taking a look:

```
>>> [cell.cell_contents for cell in f.__closure__]
[<class '__main__.Foo'>]
```

Unsurprisingly, it's the class it was defined in.  I'm not sure of a simple way of creating a new `cell` object besides using `exec`, to create a new class and method;  You could probably copy the new cell around to additional methods to be added to the new class, but both the cell and the class would be brand new.

Comment: this is definitely part of the puzzle, and once I figured out how to create a closure and pass it in, `super(Foo, self)` works. but not `super()`. hrm.